# Why we have $\sum_k= \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3k$ but $\sum_r=\int d^3r$?

Tags: solid-state-physics, conventions, integration, crystals, lattice-model

Why we have $\sum_k= \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3k$ but $\sum_r=\int d^3r$? I do not understand why the latter has not the coefficient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where have you seen the second equality?

Comment: What factors connect real-space and k-space lattice vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter also has a coefficient - since otherwise the dimensionality is wrong. In fact, very often it will be something like
$$
\sum_i f(x_i)\Delta x \rightarrow \int f(x)dx,
$$
which is the usual transition from sum to integral (see [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).) Here the number of terms in the sum goes to infinity, while $\Delta x$ becomes smaller in smaller, in such a way that the sum remains finite.

The sums over $k$ are usually done over discretized states (using the periodic boundary conditions), where
$$
k_n=\frac{2\pi n}{L}
$$
(for simplicity I consider one-dimensional case.)
We thus have something like
$$
\sum_n f(k_n)
$$
To pass to an integral we would need to have a difference $\delta k$ in the sum, which would become smaller and smaller as the number of terms in the sum increases. From our definition of $k_n$ we see that the difference between two subsequent values of $k_n$ is $$\Delta k = \frac{2\pi}{L}\left(\Leftrightarrow \frac{L\Delta k}{2\pi}=1.\right)$$ This would become smaller and smaller as $L\rightarrow +\infty.$
Thus, we can write
$$
\sum_n f(k_n)=\sum_n f(k_n)\frac{L\Delta k}{2\pi}=\frac{L}{2\pi}\sum_n f(k_n)\Delta k\rightarrow \frac{L}{2\pi}\int f(k)dk
$$
In practice $L$ usually cancels with another factor or because we are interested in the per volume properties (like concentration rather than the total number of particles, density of states per volume, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Whether $\sum_r f(r)$ cannot be written as $\int f(r)dr$ directly or not. In 3D case, $\sum_k \to \frac{1}{\Delta k}\sum_k \Delta k$. But $\sum_r \neq \frac{1}{\Delta r}\sum \Delta r$ because $\frac{1}{\Delta r} \to \infty$.

Comment: @王庆轩 same is true for $\Delta k$. I suggest adding to your question a few specific examples - you will see how it works then.